# Get div from external page, then delete an another div from it

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I need a little help, with getting content from external webpages.

I need to get a `div`, and then delete another `div` from inside it. This is my code, can someone help me?

This is the relevant portion of my XML code:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body class="domain-4 page-product-detail" > ...

         <div id="informacio" class="htab-fragment"> <!-- must select this -->
            <h2 class="description-heading htab-name">Utazás leírása</h2>
            <div class="htab-mobile tab-content">
                <p class="tab-annot">* Hivatalos ismertető</p>

                <div id="trip-detail-question"> <!-- must delete this -->
                    <form> ...</form>
                </div>

                <h3>USP</h3><p>Nagy, jól szervezett és családbarát ...</p>
                <div class="message warning-message">
                    <p>Az árak már minden aktuális kedvezményt tartalmaznak!</p>
                    <span class="ico"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ... 
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get the `div` with `id="informacio"`, and after that I need to *delete* the `div` `id="trip-detail-question"` from it including the form it contains.

This is my code, but its not working correctly :(.

```
function get_content($url){

    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = "//div[@id='informacio']";
    $entries = $xpath->query($query)->item(0);

    foreach($xpath->query("div[@id='trip-detail-question']", $entries) as $node)
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

    $var = $doc->saveXML($entries);
    return $var;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *second* XPath expression is incorrect. It tries to select a `div` *in the context* of the `div` you selected previously as its *child* node. You are trying to select:

```
//div[@id='informacio']/div[@id='trip-detail-question']
```

and that node does not exist. You want this node:

```
//div[@id='informacio']/div/div[@id='trip-detail-question']
```

which you can also select like this (allowing any element, not just `div`):

```
//div[@id='informacio']/*/div[@id='trip-detail-question']
```

or (allowing more than one nesting levels)

```
//div[@id='informacio']//div[@id='trip-detail-question']
```

In the *context* of the first `div`, the correct XPath expression would be:

```
.//div[@id='trip-detail-question']
```

If you change it in your code, it should work:

```
foreach($xpath->query(".//div[@id='trip-detail-question']", $entries) as $node)
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I almost figured it out by myself :(  And its working nicely :) as it is needed.